# prove that $x_{n+1}=c+\sqrt{x_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I prove that $x_{n+1}=c+\sqrt{x_n}$, $x_1=a>0$ and $c>0$ converges?
I know that the limit (if it exists) is $L={{2c+1+\sqrt{4c+1}}\over 2}$.
I have already prove that if $x_1<L$ then $x_n<L$ so its bounded from above but how can I prove that if $x_1<L$ then the sequence is increasing? 
I would really appreciate any hints or ideas.

Answer (score 6):

Note that we have

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x_{n-1}}}$$

Hence, if $c+\sqrt{x_1}>x_1$, then we see from $(1)$ by inductive reasoning that the sequence is always increasing.

Similarly, if $c+\sqrt{x_1}<x_1$, then the sequence is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

So you have $x_{n+1}-x_n=c+\sqrt{x_n}-x_n$. Now consider the function:
$$f(x)=c+\sqrt{x}-x,x\in R.$$
It follows
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-1.$$
You can see that when $x< \frac{1}{4}$, it has
$$f'(x)>0.$$
This means
$$f(x)>f(\frac{1}{4})=1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}>0.$$
That's
$$x_{n+1}-x_n>0,n=1,2,\cdots, \text{ if } x< \frac{1}{4}.$$

Conversly, Let $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)>0$, you can easily get the number you want $L=\frac{2c+1+\sqrt{4c+1}}{2}$.