# Show that the sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt {x_n}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> Let, $x_1=1$ and for all $n\in \Bbb N$, $x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt {x_n}$. Prove that the sequence is convergent.

I'm unable to how the sequence is monotonic increasing !
We have, $x_{n+1}-x_n=1+\sqrt{x_n}-x_n$. How can I say this is $\ge 0$ ?n Or any other way to prove this ?

Comment: More general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2010693/290189

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you think. Note that all terms are positive, so
$$x_n \le x_{n+1} \implies \sqrt{x_n} \le \sqrt{x_{n+1}} \implies 1+ \sqrt{x_n} \le 1 + \sqrt{x_{n+1}}.$$